# Writing a type-safe query in Room that selects based on a certain enum value

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-room

In a Kotlin Android project, I want to have a Room query where I select records in a database table where one of the fields has a certain enum value. Room stores my enum values by running them through a `TypeConverter` that converts them to `Int` values.

Here is my `Entity`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @TypeConverters(UserType.Converter::class)
    val type: UserType
)

enum class UserType {
    Free,
    Trial,
    Paying;

    object Converter {
        @TypeConverter
        fun toInt(userType: UserType): Int = userType.ordinal

        @TypeConverter
        fun fromInt(int: Int): UserType = values()[int]
    }
}
```

This is the query I want to write:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = ${UserType.Trial.ordinal}")
    suspend fun getTrialUsers(): Array<User>
}
```

The problem with that code is that Kotlin requires the parameter to the `Query` annotation to be a compile-time constant, but the `ordinal` value of an enum is not considered a compile-time constant. **What would be a type-safe workaround?** Currently, the non-type-safe workaround that I'm considering is to use `const` int values instead of an enum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have a simple `getUsers(type)` that does the queries wrapped with a nicer interface that includes `getTrialUsers()`.

```
@Dao
abstract class UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = :type")
    protected abstract suspend fun getUsers(type: Int): Array<User>

    suspend fun getTrialUsers(): Array<User> = getUsers(UserType.Trial.ordinal)
}
```

Comment: Good approach. You can also have the "nicer" interface in a repository as well.